# Getting the value of Account Type in Database

Tags: php

Is it possible to grab or fetch a column on a table and set it to an "if else statement"? My query has a field that indicates what type of account a user has. it is an integer that is defined 0 before registering and if you pick admin in registering it will be set to "1" otherwise "2" if just a common user. How can I able to get those value on a column of my database?

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE Username='$username' AND Password='$password'"; 

$result = @mysqli_query($connection, $query);
$row = @mysqli_num_rows($result);
if ($row>0) {
    if ($result===1) {
        echo "You are an admin";
    }else
        echo "You are not an admin";
    }
}else
    $loginnotif = $loginerror;
```

Comment: You need to fetch the data from the database and then put the condition .use can use @mysqli_fetch_array

Comment: mysqli_fetch_array is not working on me. I don't know why. that's why I use mysqli_num_rows and assumed that it will grab those fields in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way that you are checking the row count only tells you if a record was found. (or not)

This is likely NOT what you intend because you say that you have some "other field" (account type ?) that is set to 0 or 1 for admin? This has NO correlation to the row count.  Also, why the @ operators to ignore possible errors? Remove those to help troubleshoot the situation.

If mysqli_fetch_array($result) is NOT working for you, then that likely means that the query to $result may have failed (or the connection attempt before that point, which would mean the connection attempt may have failed, and passing that to the query would be invalid), and you ultimately do not have a result set from the SELECT.

The handling after the connection **AND** after the query should BOTH be checked to know their statuses.

...since you don't show the mysqli_connect() handling, which should have a similar check, try checking the query result this way:

```
// before this point, it is not known if the connection was successful ??
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

if ( $result === false ) {
    die ( "Query trouble: " . mysqli_error($connection) );
}

// At this point, the query was good, so you can use $result:
if ( 0 != mysqli_num_rows($result) ) {
    while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result) ) {
        if ( $row['accountType'] == 1 ) { // change the field to match yours
            echo "You are an admin";
        }
        else {
            echo "You are NOT an admin";
        }
    }
}
```

See the "procedural style" information at this link for example usage:
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Take a little time to see the API information at php.net for each of the mysqli_connect, mysqli_query, and the mysqli_num_rows functions. The site provides basic example usage for each one.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. :) Ive already figured out how to work on this and apply it to my Web project. Thank you. :) This is a close thread.